# OpenGL and GLUT in Eclipse on Windows

Tags: eclipse, glut

Can somebody explain please how can I import glut library to the eclipse, I can't find any explanations in net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Support for OpenGL is included in SWT
>   as of Eclipse 3.2 in the package
>   org.eclipse.swt.opengl. See the
>   GLCanvas class for a widget which
>   hosts an OpenGL context.

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/opengl/